# simple Stack implemention

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

Actually I want to implement the stacks in simple structure.

why following code showing garbage instead of item?after stack full pushing on next item it goes to infinity? There are other methods to implement stack using array. but i want to try this.

how could we implement stacks without using pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
#define size  5

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s[size];
    int top = -1,item,choice;
    char ans;

    do {
        cout << " =======================";
        cout << " \n|Implementation of Stack|\n";
        cout << " =======================";
        cout<<"\n MAIN NENUE";
        cout<<"\n 1. Push \n 2. Pop \n 3.Display ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            cout<<"\n Enter the Item to be Pushed ";
            cin>>item;
            if (top != size -1) {
                top++;
                top = item;
            } else {
                cout<<"\nStack is Full ";
            }

        break;
        case 2:
            if (top == -1) {
                cout<<"\n Stack is Empty ";
            } else {
                int item;
                item = s[top];
                top--;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if (top == -1) {
                cout<<"\n Stack is Empty ";
            } else {
                for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
                    cout<<"|" << s[i] << "|"<<endl;
                }
            }

            break;

        default:
            cout<<" \n You have Pressed Invalid Key";
            break;
        }

        cout<<"\n Do You Want To Continue ";
        cin>>ans;
    } while (ans == 'Y' || ans=='y');

    return item;
}
```

Comment: C != C++.. both are different languages

Comment: You don't really have a "data structure" here, just some variables. If you are learning C++, you want to start with a `class`. Also, C and C++ can be very different with the latest standards. In general, you should not cross tag.

Comment: Why not make your stack a class so logic is separate from I/O and so easier to stop the issues.

Comment: Please elaborate on the steps you took to display "garbage", and just what you mean by "garbage".

Comment: @NeilKirk I know few other methods. want to implement without using class or function.

Comment: @crashmstr I know both are different but I apologize for cross tag. Its not data structure nor its complete working code. that's m here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you never pushes element into your `stack`.

Change your `push` code to this.

```
if (top < (size -1)) {
            ++top;
            s[top] = item;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of these statements

```
       if (top != size -1) {
            top++;
            top = item;
```

write

```
       if (top != size -1) {
            s[++top] = item;
```

You could add some useful functions for your stack. For example

```
int s[size];
int top = -1,item,choice;
char ans;

auto is_empty = [&top] { return top == -1; };
// ...
```

then you could write

```
    case 3:
        if ( is_empty() ) {
            cout<<"\n Stack is Empty ";
        } else {
            for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
                cout<<"|" << s[i] << "|"<<endl;
            }
        }

        break;
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right! its not helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your first `if` statement. You should assign `item` to `s[top]` but not to `top` (it's because you have to store `item` in array `s[]`):

```
if (top != size -1) {
    top++;
    s[top] = item;
}
```

Comment: I've tested code just minute ago. Push/Pop/Display works fine. Are you sure you are still taking garbage on the output?